# Listing for TeX : how to add every tex command as keywords?

Tags: floats, listings, color

I'm looking for a way to color all LaTeX commands in a listing. I'm currently using a bad way to do it :

```
\lstset{
  language=TeX,
  morekeywords={caption,label,documentclass,some,latex,commands,name,...},
  morekeywords=[2]{begin,end},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  keywordstyle=[2]\color{red},
  morestring=[s]{[}{]},
  morestring=[s]{\{}{\}},
  stringstyle=\color{red},
  % some other confs
}
```

Adding every commands is, i think, a bad way to proceed. Maybe there's a way using regex ?

Example of content to colorate :

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={An example}]
\begin{document}

This is a short example to colorate.

\begin{itemize}
  \item an item
  \item another item
\end{itemize}
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) already includes most (all) (La)TeX commands already. You should only have to add new ones. The output of compiling your code snippet yields blue and red macros...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: IIRC, use `language={[LaTeX]TeX}`.

Comment: @Werner : it's what i want. `\begin` and `\end` command should be red in order to differenciate them. Topic will be edit

@Sean Allred : It's what i'm looking for this question. Just something else, can I modify the color of arguments ? like `\section{foo}` with `{foo}` in red for example.

Answer (score 1):

The minted package supports syntax highlight for tex/latex.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}
[
frame=lines,
framesep=2mm,
baselinestretch=1.2,
linenos
]{latex}
\begin{align}
        T_{\eta,s}(x)=F^{\eta'^{-1}}(F^{\eta}(x\mid s)\mid s)
        \label{eq:acuracy tranformation}
\end{align}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

When you compile you have to use the shel escape option

```
pdflatex -shell-escape texsource.tex
```

Comment: Please can you add an example? That would be easier to understand what you mean ...